# tfs buils are failing randomly

Tags: ssl, networking, tfs, build, continuous-integration

We have Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3 and several build tasks have been running. Most of the time builds are running just fine but occassionally (genetrally in the afternoon between 2-4 pm) builds are failing without a visible reason.

We get first following error on the first failed build

"*The job has been abandoned because agent **agent-xxx** did not renew the lock. Ensure agent is running, not sleeping, and has not lost communication with the service.*"

Then following builds are failing without any visible errors on TFS Web interface. But in the Event logs of the server , we see

"*Total Time:110160.1665 (Delay 0ms) (Duration 110160.1665ms) (Threshold 10ms) (Fast 19) (Truncated 0)
HostManagement.AspNetRequestContext.EndRequest:110160* "

We have set up different agents and made sure agents are running correct versions. I am gussing this is an network or ssl issue but as it fixes itself after 1 -2 hour makes the whole problem weird.

We also installed brand new agents  and flush dns, restart the iis , recycle tfs app pool. Nothing seems like the solution. We  tried to tap into network traffic with WireShark or Fiddler but it is hard to figure out what is going on wrong.

Comment: Do you try to disable the firewall and anti-virus software? Do you try to configure a agent on your TFS machine?

Comment: yup, not firewall issue. We checked the TFS machine when builds were failing , there is no unusual activity in process explorer ..etc . It is a good idea to install an agent on TFS machine (being agent requires some capabilities on TFS machine so will discuss with the rest of the team ). I saw similar issues on internet but no definitive answer. and as we cannot repeat the error , it is really hard to tackle . I am guessing TFS is being widely used as Build server and we have something wrong in our setup , am i right ?

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot a random issue as we can't reproduce the issue. And it's weird that your issue would be fixed itself after 1 -2 hour, it seems something block the communication between build agent and the server, but I'm not sure what caused this block. So you may try to configure an agent on your TFS machine to see whether you would get the block issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Sql server and TFS server were having weird 12 minutes time difference. After a while Network Time Sync was syncing these machines again and that was making builds work again. We made sure time sync is services were making properly between machines and within network. Since then we ddint get any of these errors.